# The example of monomorphism which is not injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Consider subcategory of $Ab$ of category abelian groups consisting divisible abelian groups (such groups $X$ that for any $x \in X$ and $n \in \mathbb N$ there is $y \in X$ such that $ x = ny$).

I need to show that morphism $\varphi: \mathbb R \to \mathbb T$, $t \mapsto e^{it} $ is monomorhism. It is probably easy so I'm asking for just hint.

P.s. I don't get why $\mathbb T$ is said to be divisible? It is so if we define action of $n$ as $n\cdot e^{it}: = e^{i(t+n)}$, though.

Comment: What are you calling $\Bbb T$ here? That usually denotes a torus

Comment: @AlexMathers $\mathbb{T}$ is the "1-torus", i.e. $S^1 = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| = 1 \}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concerning the divisibility of ${\mathbb T}$: The action of ${\mathbb Z}$ on ${\mathbb T}$ is uniquely determined by the abelian group structure on ${\mathbb T}$ (it is for any abelian group) by $n.\exp(it)=\exp(it)^n=\exp(itn)$. In particular, ${\mathbb T}$ being divisible means that arbitrary roots exist in ${\mathbb T}$. Can you check that for yourself? Alternatively, note that it suffices to check divisibility for ${\mathbb R}$, because images of divisible groups are again divisible, and $\exp: {\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb T}$ is surjective.

Concerning the actual question: Consider first a morphism $\psi: X\to {\mathbb R}$ of a divisible abelian group $X$ into ${\mathbb R}$ such that $\exp\circ\psi$ is the trivial homomorphism. Then, looking at it as a morphism in the category of all abelian groups, it factors through the kernel of $\exp$. How does that kernel look like? Is it divisible?

Comment: What do you mean by "trivial homomorphism"? Homomorphism to identity? Then what is the question concerning kernel about? It would be all $X$.

Comment: By the trivial homomorphism I mean the one sending every element to the zero element. When talking about the kernel I meant the kernel of $\exp$, not the one of $\exp\circ\psi$.

Comment: The kernel of $exp$ is $e^{2\pi n}$

Comment: @Vladislav Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I've already solved it, thank you.

Comment: of course not, the problem is solved, there are no more questions related.

Comment: @ Hanno I meant, of course the question can be closed.

Comment: @ Hanno sorry, I didn't know that. I've accepted it now.

Comment: @Vladislav Thanks - we can clear up the comment stack then, ok?